# In general How to find out whether client has assigned static Ip or it is dhcp client

Tags: c++, c, linux, dhcp, ioctl

I have retrieved IP, subnet and broadcast using ioctl() system call.
can anyone help me to find out whether client is static or dhcp??
I am asking about in general and using system call. it is all about client instead of interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out if the eth0 mode is static or dhcp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085222/how-to-find-out-if-the-eth0-mode-is-static-or-dhcp)

Comment: The interface doesn't have a mode, there's no dhcp built into the kernel.

Comment: I suppose, if you have the right permissions, you could trawl through `/var/log/messages`...?

Comment: Hello @all. i just wanted to know about client whether it has static IP or it is dhcp client??

Comment: @YasirMajeed: it is different question.

Comment: @teppic: i am asking about client. whether it has static IP or it is DHCP client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface itself has nothing to do with dhcp. It can be configured to have a particular IP address, gateway, etc. but that's all. This configuration, however, can be done with a smart little program called dhcp client :) So what you need is to find out who (i mean, which program) has configured your interface.

**UPDATE:**

For example, under the majority of linux distributions you may do a

```
ps aux | grep 'dhcpcd .* eth0'
```

If it gives a result like

```
/sbin/dhcpcd --netconfig -L -E -HHH -c /etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/dhcpcd-hook -t 0 -h somehostname eth0
```

you can say that eth0 is configured with dhcp

Comment: i just want to retrieve whether client has assigned static IP or it is dhcp client??

Comment: I know, but from the interface aspect, there is no difference. You need to dive into the network manager's configuration, or obtain a status from it, or something like this. It is hard to give an answer to this question in a general context. It's not just operating system, but even distribution dependent.

Answer (score -1):

use system command in c

cat /etc/network/interfaces

this will get you network information txt on screen

but first you need to set permission and for permission you user or group on linux system

Comment: 1) On which distributions does this file exist?

Comment: Usually you don't need any special permission for reading */etc/network/interfaces*. Additionally this will only tell you the configuration used during system start when not using NetworkManager. Also, a DHCP client could have been started afterwards.

Comment: 2) Why to use the `system()` command and `cat`?? Files can be perfectly read from C, tools are provided in the standard library to do so :)

Comment: 3) @scai is right :)